# Why is there no MouseMoveEvent -- or, how to use AddHandler for the mouse move event

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, mouseevent, routed-events

The [UIElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.UIElement%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class defines static `RoutedEvent` members `MouseLeftButtonDownEvent` and `MouseLeftButtonUpEvent` -- but there is no `MouseMoveEvent`.  As far as I can tell, neither does any class in the framework hierarchy.  There is the regular event definition:

```
public event MouseEventHandler MouseMove;
```

So you can write:

```
void AttachHandler(UIElement element)
{
    element.MouseMove += OnMouseMove;
}
```

but you can't use the other form, which allows you to subscribe to even handled events:

```
void AttachHandler(UIElement element)
{
    element.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseMoveEvent, new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseMove), true);
}
```

So my question is twofold:

1. Why is there no `MouseMoveEvent` defined anywhere?
2. Is there a workaround that allows you to get a notification for MouseMove events even when they are handled?

**Edit**

I see that [the MSDN docs acknowledge this as a limitation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189029%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#mouse_routed_events):

> A limitation of this technique is that the AddHandler API takes a parameter of type RoutedEvent that identifies the routed event in question. Not all Silverlight routed events provide a RoutedEvent identifier, and this consideration thus affects which routed events can still be handled in the Handled case.

**Edit #2**

Per @HansPassant, the general answer is that "MouseMove" events cannot be marked as "handled", thus they always bubble.  This is true of the TextBox, except for an apparent edge case: when you click on the TextBox's text area, thus activating the drag-to-select thingo, the "MouseMove" events no longer get triggered.  I have no idea why that would be.

---

<sub>**Note** -- for anyone curious -- I am trying to write a behavior that allows the user to drag/drop a TextBox.  The TextBox control intercepts mouse events by default, in order to allow text selection.</sub>

Comment: You can use `UIElement.PreviewMouseMoveEvent`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan well, that doesn't exist either, in Silverlight.  I guess this is just one of those features that Silverlight doesn't have.  I'm still curious to know what the best workaround would be, if any.

Comment: It is explicitly mentioned in the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598899%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):  "MouseMove cannot be used with AddHandler because there is no Handled in its event data"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is explicitly mentioned in the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598899%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> MouseMove cannot be used with AddHandler because there is no Handled in its event data

So that answers your questions:

> Why is there no MouseMoveEvent defined anywhere?

Because none is needed.

> Is there a workaround that allows you to get a notification for MouseMove events even when they are handled?

You don't need one, they can't be handled and thus always bubble.  The Window's MouseMove event handler will see them.

Comment: Ah thanks, I missed that.  "They always bubble" is true, except for  when the text-selection drag thing is active.  That is, while the left mouse button is down, I don't get the MouseMove events bubbling up.  An edge case obviously ... not clear to me why that happens, or if it's a bug.